# Git edits in one branch are causing edits in another branch without merge/push/pull

Tags: git

I have my git master - a local repo on my computer - no remote repos anywhere.

Say I'm in the dir `maths`.

I do:

```
git branch relative_imports
git checkout relative_imports
... do some work, add a file, make a file, etc.
```

Running `git status` at this point shows the changes you would expect.

If I do (without doing any merging, pulling or pushing):

```
git checkout master
git status
```

It shows the exact same output of the previous `git status`. Am I doing something wrong? I thought I wasn't supposed  to see the changes of `relative_imports` until I did `git merge relative_imports`.

Comment: Did you commit any files? It sounds to me like you added them to the index with `git add` but haven't committed them with `git commit` yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're seeing these files in `git status`, you haven't added and committed them yet. As such, they aren't part of any commit, nor any branch, so `git checkout` won't touch them.

Make them part of a commit and you'll start seeing the behavior you expect.

Comment: Don't be afraid to make "wip" commits on the branch...you can always tidy up with `rebase` after.

Comment: I just tested that and you are right. I was confusing myself since doing `git add -A :/`, `git checkout -m ""'` and then `git status` in both branches gave clean statuses, leading me to believe that a git commit in one branch had committed the changes in both branches.

Comment: So Git does not confine the changes you make to files to a branch UNTIL you have committed. Prior to committing those changes, it's as though the changes have been made to branches that are operating off the same HEAD.